# Task Mapping over a task group without using decorator

Tags: airflow, operators, airflow-2.x, airflow-taskflow

I have implemented a task group that is expected to be reused across multiple DAGs, in one of which  utilizing it in a mapping manner makes more sense. Here is the full code of my task group:

```
from airflow.utils.task_group import TaskGroup
from airflow.operators.python import BranchPythonOperator, PythonOperator
from airflow.operators.email import EmailOperator
from airflow.providers.sftp.operators.sftp import SFTPOperator
from airflow.providers.sftp.hooks.sftp import SFTPHook, SSHHook

def DeliveryGroup(group_id: str, file:str, deliver_args:dict, **kwargs) -> TaskGroup:
    with TaskGroup(group_id=group_id, **kwargs) as tg:
        # select destination type
        selector_task = BranchPythonOperator(
            task_id='destination_selector',
            python_callable=lambda: f"{deliver_args.get('type')}"
        )
        
        email_task = EmailOperator(
            task_id="email",
            to=deliver_args.get('to'),
            subject=deliver_args.get('subject'),
            cc=deliver_args.get('cc'),
            html_content=deliver_args.get('body'),
            files=[file]
        )

        sftp_task = SFTPOperator(
            task_id="sftp",
            # ssh_conn_id='YinzCam-Connection',
            sftp_hook=SFTPHook(
                remote_host=deliver_args.get('host'),
                username=deliver_args.get('username'),
                password=deliver_args.get('password'),
                port=deliver_args.get('port', 22)),
            local_filepath=[file],
            remote_filepath=[deliver_args.get('path')]
        )

        selector_task >> [email_task, sftp_task]

        return tg
```

What I would do next is to pass a list of dicts that represent separate destinations as the expansive parameter of this task group.

```
task3 = DeliveryGroup.partial(
                group_id='deliver',
                file = "my_file.csv",
            ).expand(
                args=dag.default_args.get('destinations') # a list of dicts
            )
```

However, I received this error: `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'partial'`. So what is the correct way to write a mapping over a task group without using a decorator?

A guide of syntax, references

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem:

> `DeliveryGroup` is a function in your case(not `instance`, not `module` etc)

So it's something like:

```
def my_func():
    return True

# my_func is a function. the function knows nothing about partial()
my_func.partial()  # AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'partial'
```

---

If I understand correctly what you need, here is an example:

```
def create_group(group_id: str, file: str, task_params: list[dict], group_params: dict = None) -> TaskGroup:
    group_params = group_params or {}
    
    with TaskGroup(group_id=group_id, **group_params) as group:
        # iterate through the task parameters, create operators dynamically and attach to the group
        for ix, params in enumerate(task_params):
            selector_task = BranchPythonOperator(
                task_id=f'destination_selector_{ix}',
                python_callable=lambda: f"{params.get('type')}"
            )

            email_task = EmailOperator(
                task_id=f'email_{ix}',
                to=params.get('to'),
                subject=params.get('subject'),
                cc=params.get('cc'),
                html_content=params.get('body'),
                files=[file],
            )

            sftp_task = SFTPOperator(
                task_id=f'sftp_{ix}',
                # ssh_conn_id='YinzCam-Connection',
                sftp_hook=SFTPHook(
                    remote_host=params.get('host'),
                    username=params.get('username'),
                    password=params.get('password'),
                    port=params.get('port', 22),
                ),
                local_filepath=[file],
                remote_filepath=[params.get('path')],
            )

            selector_task >> [email_task, sftp_task]

        return group


deliver = create_group(
    group_id='deliver',
    file='my_file.csv',
    group_params=dict(ui_fgcolor='#E4BE4D'),
    task_params=[
        dict(
            type='test',
            to=['blabla@mail.com'],
            cc=['blabla@so.com'],
            body='hello world',
            host='host.so.com',
            username='username1',
            password='password1',
        ),
        dict(
            type='test2',
            to=['new@mail.com'],
            cc=['new@so.com'],
            body='hello world2',
            host='host2.so.com',
            username='username2',
            password='password2',
        ),
        # ...
    ]
)
```